# Socket connection is closed every minute

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I'm configuring a **Flask-SocketIO** server.

When locally connecting a socket (http://127.0.0.1:5000), it's normally working. But after deploying it into my **GCP virtual machine**, sockets connected over https are closed and reconnected every minute as shown below (looks like socket connection requests are timed out at this interval).

[image: Dev console screenshot]

I've already tried with all async modes, including `eventlet`, `gevent`, and `threading` as well as `gunicorn` and `uwsgi`. Some configurations allow a **2-min timeout** but no approach resolves the issue fundamentally.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [topic](https://medium.com/johnjjung/how-to-use-gcp-loadbalancer-with-websockets-on-kubernetes-using-services-ingresses-and-backend-16a5565e4702) its because of the Google loadbalancer

Br

Comment: Your advice was right!

Comment: Great just mark as correct answer :)